# Understanding the Aspect ratio constraint and multiplier

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, autolayout, constraints

I have created a `UIScrollview` programmatically. And I have added some programmatically created buttons onto this scroll view. Button height is 30. But the button width changing according to the screen size.

```
float scrollYearX=btnLeftArrow.frame.origin.x+btnLeftArrow.frame.size.width+15;
float scrollYearY=40.0;
float scrollYearWidth=btnRightArrow.frame.origin.x-15-scrollYearX;
float scrollYearHeight=50.0;
scrollYear=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollYearX, scrollYearY, scrollYearWidth, scrollYearHeight)];

[scrollYear setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[scrollYear setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

[vwParent addSubview:scrollYear];
int buttonX=0;

for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(buttonX, 0, scrollYearWidth/5, 30)];
    [btn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0]];

    int mod=i%2;
    if (mod==1) {
        [btn setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    }
    else
    {
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(yearClick :) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)backYear] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        if (backYear==year) {
            btnCurrentYear=btn;
            [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yearSelect"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        backYear++;
    }
    [scrollYear addSubview:btn];
    btnLast=btn;
    buttonX=buttonX+btn.frame.size.width;
}
[scrollYear setContentSize:CGSizeMake(btnLast.frame.origin.x+btnLast.frame.size.width, scrollYearHeight)];
[scrollYear setContentOffset:CGPointMake(btnCurrentYear.frame.origin.x-(btnLast.frame.size.width*2),0)];
```

My problem is which constraint I should use inorder to display this correctly in every device. Here I have attached how it shows on 6s and ipad pro. How can I make the ipad pro visual same as the 6s.

Button loks in 6s

[image]

Button looks in ipad pro
[image]

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your button background width got scaled. you need to use resizable image to keep the round edge. Change your background image with follow:

```
UIImage* backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yearSelect"];
backgroundImage = [backgroundImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, backgroundImage.size.width/2-1, 0, backgroundImage.size.width/2)];
[btn setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: what did you mean by the resizable image? and how can I use them?

Comment: @user1960169 see UIImage API, there should have a method like resizableImage. Now I am use iPhone client and can't check the doc.